# Ordering table containing boolean

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to order my table alphabetically, but with data that is active first, then alphabetically where active is false after this. I am doing this through a query in my table but am unsure how to actually do this. As it stands right now the query simply orders alphabetically by the long name. Note: The table contains a long_name column which is a string and an active column which is a boolean.

Query used in controller:

```
@arrest_reason = ArrestReason.order(:long_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the boolean column to the order clause too:

```
@arrest_reason = ArrestReason.order(active: :desc, long_name: :asc)
```

I guess that your database encodes `false` as `0` internally and `true` as `1`. Therefore, you have to order the boolean columns descending when you want to have the active records first.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Seems simple now I'm looking at it. Thank You!